# Play Newsstand kind of animating reveal effect toolbar color change ,how?

Tags: android

Many of you might've tried the new google play newsstand with the all new material design.It looks pretty amazing.

I would love to know how to achieve the looks it has.
So let me narrow it down for you.

1. How do I do the parallax effect , scroll down toolbar disappears and the reappears as a smaller one on a slight scroll to the top and then fades into the bigger toolbar.

2.the toolbar reveal animation when we swipe tabs.

It has two components , one - the circle in the middle of the toolbar fades in , two - it continues as another circle reveals itself along with an animated color change .

I have made no progress in my research so I come here..nonetheless I'll keep searching for those in my situation.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android provides this feature in support design library now.
You can achieve it by using

```
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
```

Comment: yep , this was quite a while back tho . This will definitely help others stumbling here :)

Answer (score 2):

Ok ,

Research still going on ..

got some details..

The actionbar is actually a toolbar in the newstand application and further it is a parralax action bar viewpager with some extra animations.

and further the toolbar has a fading action bar effect but a little more advanced .. the moment you scroll up the bar is back and the transitions into a bigger transparent bar.

one doubt yet left ,

how does a list item persist partially on top of a toolbar ?

Comment: How are they actually implementing any of this?